# Excel 2013 - ActiveX warning despite allowing all ActiveX in Trust Center

Tags: vba, excel, macros, activex

I have an issue I'm struggling with, and it bothers me to no end. However, I can't come up with a decent solution, so I'm turning to you folks for advice.

The problem is as follows:
I have a .xlsm file containing a few macros. The macros use Forms, and specifically they also use TreeView objects in them (through mscomctl.ocx). I have gone through the Trust Center, and set every setting to it's unsafest form (allow all ActiveX, allow all VBA, no 'safe mode' for web documents, etc etc...

I can open the file, but when I call the macro relying on forms, I get a warning message labeled 'Microsoft Forms', with the following error message:

> This application is about to initialize ActiveX Controls that might be
>   unsafe. If you trust the source of this document, select Yes and the
>   control will be initialized using your document settings.

It both surprises me (I said to allow it all in the settings, didn't I?) and annoys me (well, not the first time, but me and my coworkers use it on a daily basis and it gets on my nerves).

Does anyone have a clue whatsoever as to:
1) Why this happens? 
2) How I can avoid the message?

I'm open to both solutions on altering the Excel file, or settings I have to alter on local machines (<20 PC's).

Details:

> Windows 8.1, running Excel 2013.
>  The macro-code is 'safe', it's built by our company employees (myself included). Code is password-protected so can't be meddled with.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps

1) Launch Excel
2) Click "File - Options"
3) Click "Trust Center"
4) Select "ActiveX Settings"
5) Modify "ActiveX Settings for all Office Applications" from the default ("Prompt me..." - see above) to "Disable all controls without notification"

Comment: A few issues with your answer: 1) I do not want to disable them, I need them. 2) If you'd mean 'enable' rather then disable, that's what I had toggled already. Which is why it stumps me I still get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

We see same error in an Excel solution with a TreeView form-component on 64-bit Win7 and solution here is to re-register mscomctl.ocx

Bat-file code:

```
regsvr32 /U "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX"

regsvr32 /S "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX"
```

Regards